"Is not terminated with newline" Ren'py
I had launched my programm, but it gave me a traceback that says: "line 9: is not terminated with newline". I don't see a mistake. Can someone explain it to me?
init:

    #Название мода

    $ mods["test_mod"]=u"Саманта: Reworked"
    
    #Персонажи
    
    $ sm = Character (u'Саманта', color = "0000ff", ctc = "ctc_animation", ctc_position = "fixed", "what_color = "ffdd7f", drop_shadow = [ (2, 2) ], drop_shadow_color = "#000", what_drop_shadow = [ (2, 2) ], what_drop_shadow_color = "#000")
    
    #Изображения
    
    image nk1W = "mods/S_Reworked/cg/331470_16.jpg"
    

